# Running NodeJS with TLS protocol

Tags: node.js, ssl, cmd, openssl, tls1.2

*Generated a self-signed certificate with OpenSSL and copied the certificate & the private key to the required destination folder.*

*To create an HTTPS server, we require two things: an SSL certificate, and Node's built-in https module.*

*With Node.js installed, I tried the following JavaScript to run from the command Line* 
**TLSServer.js**

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = 8081; //3000;
var host = '127.0.0.1'; //192.168.1.135
var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('private-key.pem'), // /path/to/private-key.pem
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem') // /path/to/certificate.pem
    };
```

**TLSClient.js**

```
var client = tls.connect(port, host, options, function() {
    console.log('connected');
    if (client.authorized) {
        console.log('authorized: ' + client.authorized);
        client.on('data', function(data) {
            client.write(data);    // Just send data back to server
        });
    } else {
        console.log('connection not authorized: ' + client.authorizationError);
    }
});
```

**Actual Output:**

```
cmd>node TLSServer.js
openssl config failed: error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error
```

---

```
cmd>node TLSClient.js
openssl config failed: error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error
events.js:193
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:8081
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1031:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1052:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1195:14)
```

What might be the reason for getting this issue:
openssl config failed: error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error

---

**httpserver.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var options = { 
key: fs.readFileSync('private-key.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.write("You are connected to https server");
  res.end("\n hello world \n");
}).listen(8080)
```

> https://localhost:8080

From browser I used to get the following output:

```
You are connected to https server
  hello world
```

But not with TLS Client/Server. But what might be there to modify in OpenSSL config file?

Comment: maybe insufficient privileges ; is your cmd launched with administrator account ?

Comment: You might need to install libraries to support openssl

Comment: @EugèneAdell Yes

Comment: @Malice what are the commands needed to run

Comment: First of all, did you generate the key using openssl command on the same machine ?

Comment: Also see ["OPENSSL_CONF" variable](https://www.google.com/search?q="OPENSSL_CONF"+variable). It usually shows up due to WAMP with PHP and Windows systems.

Comment: @Malice Yes I did it on same machine. Do you know what?... might be done with config file. Look at the bottom of the Edited the post

Answer (score 0):

***Solved `openssl config failed: error:02001005:system library:fopen:Input/output error`  by adding the path of openssl.cnf in Environment Variables -> System Variables***

```
OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cnf
```

***To validate it you can type in the shell:***

```
echo %OPENSSL_CONF%
```

But still I'm getting error with **TLSServer.js**

```
cmd>node TLSServer.js
```

```
 module.js:544
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\TLSServer.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:682:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:613:3
```